# Objective-C : Odd Behavior With UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

When a user taps a 'Sign In' button on my app, a view animates into view as such:

```
- (IBAction)popLoginView:(id)sender {

    CGRect frame=self.animationView.frame;
    frame.origin.y=0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
        self.animationView.frame=frame;
    }];
}
```

The original y origin was 800, so, off the screen.

However, when a user begins to edit a UITextField on the animationView, animationView disappears. The view's original content shows, with the keyboard present. I can confirm that typing into the keyboard still populates the textfield, even though I can't see it anymore :(

Why would this be happening?

Comment: You must be changing the origins in textDidChange or some similar method. Or animationView isn't properly being set

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoLayout then your frame change will be discarded when AutoLayout next calculates everything. What you need to do is add a constraint to the y position and then animate the constraint instead of the frame

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. do you have a code sample for adding a constraint to the y position?

Comment: How are you configuring your view in the first place? How is it being positioned on the vertical axis?

Comment: basically I just have the view top space initially set to 1 from bottom layout, so it is just off the screen.